# How can I combine EC.elementToBeClickable() with .first() to return the first element?

Tags: selenium, protractor

Currently, I'm using:

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('div[ng-model="loginInput"]')), 5000));
```

However, this returns multiple elements.  I do not want to use a messy xpath or css selector as the path in this case is long.

My browser.wait condition works, however the console returns:

```
WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("div[ng-model=\"loginInput\"]") - the first result will be used
WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("div[ng-model=\"loginInput\"]") - the first result will be used
```

Can I use .all and .first() on elementToBeClickable() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to get the first element matching a locator using `first()`:

```
var elm = $$('div[ng-model="loginInput"]').first();
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000));
```

Another, if you want to wait for all elements to be clickable, you make a *custom expected condition* combining the individual `elementToBeClickable` using `EC.and` and `reduce()` (not tested):

```
var allElementsToBeClickable = function(elements) {
  return elements.all().reduce(function(acc, elm) {
      return EC.and(acc, EC.elementToBeClickable(elm));
  }, function () {});
};

var elements = $$('div[ng-model="loginInput"]');
browser.wait(allElementsToBeClickable(elements), 5000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get respective element in the array you want to use, by using
element.all(by.css('.xyz')).get(0);